# How can I avoid media query overlap?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, fluid-layout

The cascade is what makes CSS special and powerful. But in the case of media queries, overlap *can* seem problematic.

Consider the following CSS (continuing [rules for CSS media query overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241531/what-are-the-rules-for-css-media-query-overlap-rwd)):

```css
/* Standard - for all screens below 20em */

body { color: black; font-size: 1em; }

/* Query A - slightly wider, mobile viewport */

@media (min-width: 20em) and (max-width: 45em) {
    body { color: red; } /* supposed to be unique for this width */
}

/* Query B - everything else */

@media (min-width: 45em) {
    body { font-size: larger; } /* because viewport is bigger */
}
```

So when the screen is exactly 45em wide, the overlap at 45em [will be treated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13611538/1779823) according to the standard CSS cascade:

- All `max-width: 45em` definitions will be applied first,
- and all `min-width: 45em` will be applied thereafter.

Consider these two conditions:

- All text would normally be `black`, but *Query A* is unique and has `color: red`.
- Since *Query B* is for larger viewports, it's text has the CSS `font-size: larger`.

Therefore, at a width of exactly 45em, we'd get **big and red text**. *What would be the best solution to avoid this?*

---

I see two possibilities:

1. Re-declare the text to have `color: black` in *Query B*, but then you're managing two declarations if you choose to change the `color` in the future. (Of course, not such a problem with this single line of code, but imagine there's a lot of other declarations and selectors.)
2. Avoid overlap by using pixel values like `max-width: 799px` and `min-width: 800px`, but then you're using pixels — I guess they could be 49.9375em and 50em, respectively. Though what if the default is no longer 16em and something gets rounded? And we're [still not certain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13611538/1779823) what happens at that gap. (A black hole that breaks the space-time continuum?)

Both have their drawbacks... any other ideas?

Comment: You're over-analyzing:  you would never write styles like that.  Media queries are typically used to massage the elements for the viewport in question.  There's no reason to choose number like 49.9375em as your breakpoint over 49.99999em.

Comment: @cimmanon, I meant that more as a side point (feel free to ignore the weird `em` values, was just doing it to keep the question consistent — I considered writing the whole question in `px` but I prefer `em`)

Comment: @Baumr--I think cimmanon's point was that you should use your #2 solution, but set the value to `49.99999em` on the `max-width` so that you should never have a "gap" to deal with (like you might with `49.9375em`).

Comment: Browsers round that off when computing pixel values, so as I understand, at `50em` it'll still apply both.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only reliable way to create two mutually exclusive `@media` blocks for any given media query is to use `not` to negate it in one of the blocks. Unfortunately, this means repeating your media query once for each `@media` block. So, instead of this for example:

```css
@media (max-width: 49.9375em) {
    body {
        color: red;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 50em) {
    body {
        font-size: larger;
    }
}
```

You would have this:

```css
/* 
 * Note: Media Queries 4 still requires 'not' to be followed by a
 * media type (e.g. 'all' or 'screen') for reasons I cannot comprehend.
 */
@media not all and (min-width: 50em) {
    body {
        color: red;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 50em) {
    body {
        font-size: larger;
    }
}
```

[Interactive jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/mhF6V)

This is very effective at closing the gap with range media features like `width` and `height` since it essentially turns this into an either-or scenario. But, like your first two options, it isn't perfect: as mentioned, you have to repeat the same media query twice, and add `not` to one of them. There is no if/else construct for `@media` as described in [Conditional Rules 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-conditional/#at-media).

---

Although I mention this in my answer to your previous question:

> From my experiments it would seem Safari on iOS rounds all fractional pixel values to ensure that either one of `max-width: 799px` and `min-width: 800px` will match, even if the viewport is really 799.5px (which apparently matches the former).

It should be noted, still, that I've noticed some quirks when it comes to rounding. That said, I haven't been able to find a fractional value that would evade *both* media queries and end up not receiving styles from either set of rules (which, by the way, is the worst that can happen, so don't worry about potentially creating a space-time rift). That must mean browsers — at least, Safari as I've tested — do a reasonable job of ensuring they satisfy media queries even if you have values that differ (by exactly 1 CSS pixel).

When it comes to units with larger gaps that can be observed on desktop browsers, though, like ems, there is a much larger margin of error. For example, one comment suggests using 49.99999em instead of something more arbitrary than 49.9375em, but apparently there is a difference, at least with a default font size of 16px.

I simplified your code, changed the media queries to use decimal values, and put the code in jsFiddle:

```css
@media (max-width: 49.9375em) {
    body {
        color: red;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 50em) {
    body {
        font-size: larger;
    }
}
```

If you resize the Result pane to exactly 800 pixels (the text will update to guide you along), you actually end up with different results depending on whether [`@media (max-width: 49.9375em)` is used](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/dMtBF), or [`@media (max-width: 49.99999em)` is used](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/dMtBF/1) (I was surprised by this too)...

Either way, you're right: option 2 has its drawbacks too. I'm not particularly fond of it, to be honest, because I wouldn't want to crack my head over device and user agent quirks which are out of my control. If you're like me, I suppose it would be better to go through the inconvenience of redeclaring your rules at the cost (?) of being more vigilant around your code, as that's at least still within your control as an author.

Comment: Thank you! In your first paragraph, do I understand correctly: it should be fine to do what I've done in my question? Just to clarify. Also, your suggestions of re-declaring rules is an option in simple cases, no doubt, but if these queries get more complex it can be problematic for a large site (not my case at the moment). I am starting to feel that this is a limitation with the `min-width` and `max-width` usage in media queries. Perhaps a declaration like `below-width` and `above-width` might be useful *in addition* to this — allowing to select all values above a certain one, except it.

Comment: @Baumr: Your suggestion of `below-width` and `above-width` gives me an idea, but I'm not sure if it goes with what exactly you're asking. Have a look at the edit once I'm done with it.

Comment: Wow, what a freakin' good answer! I'm considering making another account and up-voting it again ;D Thanks Bolt!

Comment: @Baumr: Suspending over something like this would be extremely awkward :) You can always award a bounty instead!

Comment: Any news on this topic? Have browsers begun treating px and em media queries the same yet with regards to zoom? Have any solutions to the overlap problem been found? Thanks!

Comment: If you are using CSS Media Queries 4, why bother with negation, and not simply use `width < 50em` and `width >= 50em`? However, if a solution with wide support is required, check [this answer on a duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41449476/media-queries-running-weird-because-of-non-integer-width/60311147#60311147).

Comment: @Yeti: I don't remember if those operators were around at the time this was written, and just never got around to updating my answer to mention those. Those would definitely work better here.

Comment: @BoltClock it's worth noting that if the original query has `only screen and ...` for example, using `not screen and ...` in the inverted query doesn't exactly work as intended. It would **always** apply the CSS to every other media type (which is obviously the negation of _"never apply to other media types"_ in the original). We may have to go with `@media only screen and (max-width: 49.99999em)` in such a case. Shame that CSS media queries don't have an `or` operator.

Comment: @ADTC: You can nest at-media rules, or use <link/style media="screen">, to work around the media type limitation. For example, `@media screen { @media not (min-width: 50em) {...} }`, or `<style media="screen">@media not (min-width: 50em) {...}</style>` I don't remember if at-media nesting was fully supported the last time I updated this answer, but I know [I updated another answer with this information in 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746581/nesting-media-rules-in-css/11747166#11747166).

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock, I learnt something new :) [Support seems reasonable at 96.75%](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_at-rules_media_nested-queries)

Comment: @ADTC: I stopped being active a couple of years ago as a developer altogether, let alone on Stack, but I'm glad most of my CSS knowledge is still relevant and I can still teach people new things :)

Comment: @BoltClock btw we can't do `@media not (min-width: 50em)` in the second level, since `not` requires a media type. I'm supposing `@media only screen { @media not screen and (min-width: 50em) {` should work since the first level has excluded other types (second `screen` could be `all`). It appears so, based on [this truth table analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WItp.png).

Comment: @ADTC: [That requirement was removed in Media Queries 4.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455958/why-does-not-some-width-xem-media-query-never-fire/24456052#24456052)

Answer (score 1):

For me, the best way is to keep a gap of 0.01em:

```
@media (min-width: 20em) and (max-width: 44.99em) {
    body { color: red; } /* supposed to be unique for this width */
}
@media (min-width: 45em) {
    body { font-size: larger; } /* because viewport is bigger */
}
```

I recommend you to read this article for the details and the comparison of the [different solutions to prevent media query overlapping](http://tzi.fr/CSS/Responsive/Prevent-double-breakpoint).

Cheers,
Thomas.