# border-radius not working in Chrome? Any workaround?

Tags: google-chrome, css

I have set `border-radius` (and `-moz-border-radius` for the older browsers) to 20px, and I have it working beautifully in Safari and Firefox. Then, I open up Chrome and it's refusing to accept the defined `border-radius`. Any suggestions to work around this in Chrome?

**See the CSS coding in action here:** http://jsfiddle.net/MAYea/

**Screenshot in Safari:**

[image: Safari]

**Screenshot in Chrome:**

[image: Chrome]

Comment: I just tested it in Chrome. `:before` and `:after` requires the `border-radius: 20px;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not that `border-radius` isn't working, it's that `overflow` is failing to hide the overflow.

This is actually a new bug in Chrome. I have a similar problem on my [Doomsday clock](http://adamhaskell.net/misc/doomsday) even though it worked perfectly in an earlier version of Chrome.

As a workaround, you can specify the `border-radius` on the contained elements as well as the container.

Comment: Chrome is like some kind of new breed of IE.

Comment: Very true. It's sad when almost all of the CSS3 stuff I've been doing works in IE10 but not in Chrome...

Comment: Forget CSS3; it's still getting many parts of CSS2.1 wrong where IE8 gets them right (although to be fair, IE8 screws up in its own ways too)...

Comment: Yes, I have. Also: text shadows. Those were extremely hideous in Chrome and I couldn't use it for like the first 8 versions because it made my display text (e.g. headings, not body text) unreadable. I've been of the opinion that Microsoft are getting their act together - and doing it pretty well. That said, IE9/IE10 still have some new issues of their own, e.g. [they don't implement the `not` keyword in media queries correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634326/how-to-avoid-media-query-overlap/13649011#13649011).

Comment: Hey, have you seen [IE10's advertising techniques](http://thebrowseryoulovedtohate.com)? Seems quite effective and accurate to me! Also humble, in some ways. Like they're acknowledging that they have a crappy history.

Comment: I've seen it, and I find it kind of corny IMO. But it has some merit; they really have been getting their act together.

Comment: Now they just have to convince the haters about that ^_^ Anyways, back to playing with `animation` stuff - haven't had this much fun since I discovered `setInterval`.

Comment: As a designer with OCD this is tough news to digest. Applying the style to child elements just doesn't look right. I may have to switch to an image-based stylization now. Either way, thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, it helped to add

```
z-index: 0; /* or some other value */
```

but also

```
transform: translateY(0);
```

seems like this is enabling some kind of different rendering (guess nothing with 3d context like we sometime do to FORCE GPU rendering...)

the reason why this works I cannot not explain, maybe somebody else can?

I have this particular problem right now, with latest Chrome v44 on OS X 10.10.5...and yes, I know that this was "fixed" and it's an old question =)...

EDIT: Found the same fix in another SO-Question, check here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25206004/5215202)

Answer (score 1):

`-webkit-border-radius:` is what your looking for I think?

Comment: Going to try it out. Hang on!

Answer (score 1):

Add the `border-radius: 20px;` CSS rule to both `:before` and `:after`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bobthyasian/MAYea/6/)

Answer (score 0):

```
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
border-radius: 20px;


 -webkit-border-radius: for the Chrome
```

If you need it try this javascript library from [here](http://css3pie.com/)

Comment: Chrome has supported the unprefixed version for a significant amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
border-radius: 100
```

Instead of,

```
border-radius: 100px
```

it will do the job in IE but **not in Chrome**.