# Adding directional controls (prev/next) to switch between tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've just finished a creating a bare bones JavaScript tabs functionality for website. Right now I'm having a bit of problem trying to add directional functions in order to switch between tabs. Here is what I've created so far. I'm not sue on how I can increment or decrement the `index` in order to use the directional arrows to switch tabs and also the content

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tabs-list li:first-child').addClass('active'),
    $('.tab-content .show-content:first-child').addClass('active');

  $('.tabs-list li').click(function(e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
      var tabIndex = $(this).index();
      var nthChild = tabIndex + 1;

      // select the right elements
      var $tabsList = $(this).parent();
      var $tabContent = $tabsList.next('.tab-content');

      $tabsList.find('li.active').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $tabContent.find('.show-content').removeClass('active');
      $tabContent.find('.show-content:nth-child(' + nthChild + ')').addClass('active');
    }
  })

  $('.prev').on('click', function() {});

  $('next').on('click', function() {});
})
```

```css
.tabs-list li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.tab-content .show-content {
  display: none
}

.tab-content .show-content.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

  <ul class="tabs-list">
    <li>Tab 1</li>
    <li>Tab 2</li>
    <li>Tab 3</li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="show-content">
      Content 1
    </div>

    <div class="show-content">
      Content 2
    </div>

    <di>
      Content 3
    </di>

  </div>

</div>

<ul>
  <li class="prev">Prev</li>
  <li class="next">Next</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using jQuery [**.prev()**](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) and [**.next()**](https://api.jquery.com/next/) methods. You just need to get the current `.active` tab and change it accordingly.

Here's the code you need:

```
$('.prev').on('click', function() {
  var current = $('.tab-content .show-content.active');
  if (current.prev('.tab-content .show-content')[0]) {
    current.removeClass('active');
    current.prev('.tab-content .show-content').addClass('active');
  }
});

$('.next').on('click', function() {
  var current = $('.tab-content .show-content.active');
  if (current.next('.tab-content .show-content')[0]) {
    current.removeClass('active');
    current.next('.tab-content .show-content').addClass('active');
  }
});
```

**Demo:**

[This is a **working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/chsdk/vz4nq10w/) and a working Demo snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tabs-list li:first-child').addClass('active'),
    $('.tab-content .show-content:first-child').addClass('active');

  $('.tabs-list li').click(function(e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
      var tabIndex = $(this).index();
      var nthChild = tabIndex + 1;

      // select the right elements
      var $tabsList = $(this).parent();
      var $tabContent = $tabsList.next('.tab-content');

      $tabsList.find('li.active').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $tabContent.find('.show-content').removeClass('active');
      $tabContent.find('.show-content:nth-child(' + nthChild + ')').addClass('active');
    }
  })

  $('.prev').on('click', function() {
    var current = $('.tab-content .show-content.active');
    if (current.prev('.tab-content .show-content')[0]) {
      current.removeClass('active');
      current.prev('.tab-content .show-content').addClass('active');
    }
  });

  $('.next').on('click', function() {
    var current = $('.tab-content .show-content.active');
    if (current.next('.tab-content .show-content')[0]) {
      current.removeClass('active');
      current.next('.tab-content .show-content').addClass('active');
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.tabs-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tab-content .show-content {
  display: none
}

.tab-content .show-content.active {
  display: block;
}

.as-console-row-code {
  display: none;
}

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

  <ul class="tabs-list">
    <li>Tab 1</li>
    <li>Tab 2</li>
    <li>Tab 3</li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="show-content">
      Content 1
    </div>

    <div class="show-content">
      Content 2
    </div>

    <div class="show-content">
      Content 3
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<ul>
  <li class="prev">Prev</li>
  <li class="next">Next</li>
</ul>
```

---

### **Edit:**

To make it loop in a cyclic way and doesn't stop in first or last elements, we should just implement that in the `else` block of our `if` statement, so it won't stop.

Here's how will be your code:

```
$('.prev').on('click', function() {
  var current = $('.tab-content .show-content.active');
  if (current.prev('.tab-content .show-content')[0]) {
    current.removeClass('active');
    current.prev('.tab-content .show-content').addClass('active');
  } else {
    current.removeClass('active');
    $(".tab-content .show-content:last").addClass('active');
  }
});

$('.next').on('click', function() {
  var current = $('.tab-content .show-content.active');
  if (current.next('.tab-content .show-content')[0]) {
    current.removeClass('active');
    current.next('.tab-content .show-content').addClass('active');
  } else {
    current.removeClass('active');
    $(".tab-content .show-content:first").addClass('active');
  }
});
```

And this is [an **updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/chsdk/vz4nq10w/1/) taking in consideration these changes.

Comment: Thank you for this, didn't know it was that simple. Is there a way I can make it loop for the directional arrows part. When I reach the last tab and click `next` it doesn't go back to the first tab. Haven't tried using this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628500/how-do-i-loop-next`

Comment: @clestcruz Yes we just need to add a treatement in the `else` block of our `if` statement, you can check my Edit.