# How to switch between CSS rule sets, based on available parent width (not viewport width)?

Tags: css, cross-browser, media-queries

I know that `@media` can be used to detect properties of the whole viewport, and then switch among CSS rule sets based on different types of media/widths, etc ..

But how does one switch between CSS rules based on the width of parent `div`, etc ?

This code preview shows the footer of my page, with some elements changed/removed:

**Liveweave:** http://liveweave.com/JtUxpF *(Switch to **Split V** or **View** mode from the top menu)*

[image]

On the right side of the footer, there is a small form (*marked with the red arrow in the picture above*). This form has a `@media` separation applied to it, like so:

```
@media all and (min-width: 270px) {
    /* Apply first set of CSS rules */
}

@media not all and (min-width: 270px) {
/* Apply second set of CSS rules */
}
```

**Problem:**

My idea was to actually apply CSS rules based on *the width available to the form from the parent `div`*. However the CSS rules are currently applied based on *the width of the screen/viewport*.

**If you reduce your window's width to less than 270 pixels, you'll see the visual change in the form's look!**

So how can I choose and apply between two different sets of CSS rules, based on the width available to the form, instead of the viewport width itself ?

Comment: I can't think of a single way in pure css. What rules are you trying to apply and why? Perhaps there are other ways around the issue.

Comment: I want to make the footer show properly on less width devices too (handhelds, etc), so I want to create different rules for this form. This can be done using `@media` of course, but `@media` reads the whole screen's width, whereas I want to separate CSS rules based on the width available to the form from its parent `div`. For example, screen width can be 750 pixels, but each footer column gets 33% of this, so the width available to the form is 250 pixels, not 750. Since 250 is less than 270 (which is my threshold), I want the CSS to change ..

Comment: But that's predictable, isn't it? If the form will always be 33% of the viewport width, then you can guarantee that the viewport threshhold would be 810 (ish).

Comment: Yes you're right there, but that 33% hardcoding is only temporary. It's going to be variable in the future, so I guess the question is still valid .. Plus, I think it would be interesting to know how to solve such a problem ..

Answer (score 1):

Not possible in pure css. The equivalents of "if" statements in css is currently limited to media queries and selectors, neither of which get you what you need. You can use something like less or sass to do what you're trying to do, or you can generate rules dynamically using a server-side or javascript approach.

sass: http://sass-lang.com/
less: http://lesscss.org

There is some support for math in css (calc()), but no ability to use those as conditional clauses.