# Why does `not (some-width: Xem)` media query never fire?

Tags: css, media-queries, negation

I'm trying to negate the `max-device-width` media query (the reason for this is I don't won't both `(max-device-width: X)` and `(min-device-width: X)` to fire if the device has precisely that width). Unfortunately, the `not (min-or-max-some-width: X)` media queries never fire.

Here's [a small fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X94xx/). I expect two yellow lines on the desktop and two red lines on mobile. What I get is only one yellow line on the desktop (the last one) and only one red line on mobile (the first one).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When Media Queries was first introduced, it required the `not` keyword to be followed by a media type in order for the media query to be valid. It seems strange, but [that's just how the grammar was defined](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#syntax) (see the `media_query` production).

This is now fixed in [Media Queries level 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/#mq-syntax) (see the `<media_not>` production), so what you have should work as expected in browsers that conform to MQ4. However, none of the browsers that have begun shipping level 4 media features has implemented the new grammar yet.

In the meantime, you'll need to add a media type. If the media type is not important, use `all`:

```
not all and (max-device-width: X)
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/X94xx/1)

Comment: @Septagram: It does. It *might* help if you added `all and` to the rest of your media queries. The addition of `not` simply takes the entire media query and negates it.

Comment: What if I need to specify several media queries and negate only one of them, e. g. what I intend is `(min-some-parameter: 12em) and not (max-another-parameter: 15em)`?

Comment: @Septagram: This is supposed to be made possible by nesting your `@media` rules, but [that's not completely supported across browsers yet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746581/nesting-media-rules-in-css/11747166#11747166). I'm not sure if there are workarounds, but I'd encourage you to post that separately - it's a pretty good question. Meanwhile, I'm curious to see if they're willing to take syntax enhancements for MQ level 4...