# Is it possible to do a CSS @supports check on a @media rule?

Tags: css, media-queries

The @support rule allows one to do a feature query on CSS properties. I am wondering whether it is possible to do a feature check on specifically @media rules?

For example, I like to know if the browser supports the @media pointer or any-pointer condition:

```
@supports @media (pointer:fine) {
```

Or

```
@supports @media (pointer) {
```

This does not seem to work. Should it work?

**Edit**: This is not a duplicate of the referenced question. Perhaps I should clarify the question to explain why this is a different question, so here goes:

I do not want to nest @supports inside @media or vice versa. I want to feature detect whether the @media query itself is supported, in particular the @media rule for pointer. This is a completely different scenario from just nesting a random support query inside a media query.

Comment: tl;dr you need to nest the media query inside the  @supports brackets.

Comment: I'm not sure but have you tried nesting something like https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mmYNgp?

Comment: @tylerh: the question is how?

Comment: @MichaelCoker: Thanks, I created a fork of your starting point:
https://codepen.io/fchristant/pen/BRgoKN

It basically proves that this approach does not work. It does not detect the rule nested inside @ media, yet on its own without nesting, it does work. So my question still stands.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> This does not seem to work. Should it work?

No; `@supports` only supports property declarations, not at-rules or indeed any other grammatical construct in CSS. You're not looking to check for support for the `@media` rule anyway; you're trying to check for support for specific media features. But `@supports` doesn't support that either, even though media features share the same declaration syntax with property declarations.

To that end, you don't need the `@supports` rule at all. To check if a browser supports a certain media feature, simply write a `@media` rule with a media query list containing both the media feature and its negation:

```css
@media not all and (pointer), (pointer) {
  p { color: green; }
}
```

```html
<p>If this text is green, your browser supports the <code>pointer</code> media feature.
```

(Note that Media Queries 4 removes the restriction of `not` requiring a media type from MQ3, so the negation really ought to be `not (pointer)`, but [no browser supports this yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455958/why-does-not-some-width-xem-media-query-never-fire/24456052#24456052) and a media type is still required.)

Browsers that don't recognize the `pointer` media feature will interpret the `@media` rule as `@media not all, not all` (in spite of the `not` in the `not all and (pointer)` media query). See [section 3.2 of the spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries-4/#error-handling), which says

> An unknown <mf-name> or <mf-value>, or disallowed <mf-value>, results in the value “unknown”. A <media-query> whose value is “unknown” must be replaced with not all.

If you need to apply CSS for when a browser does *not* support a media feature, these error handling rules mean you'll need to take advantage of the cascade (and if you don't know the original values in advance, you may be stuck):

```css
p { color: red; }

@media not all and (pointer), (pointer) {
  p { color: currentcolor; }
}
```

```html
<p>If this text is red, your browser does not support the <code>pointer</code> media feature.
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for! I do have one follow-up question for the sake of completeness: what would be the syntax in your example to do the opposite? To check if a browser does NOT support pointer?

Comment: @Ferdy: The cascade will be your friend in that case. I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: I saw it happen in real-time, you are fast. Thanks!

Comment: This is just beautiful! For completion the answer for a pointer value: `@media not all and ( pointer: fine ), ( pointer: fine ) {}`