# CSS media query select complement of width interval

Tags: css, media-queries, not-operator

I'm working on a webpage where I often need to use media queries like the following:

```
@media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1280px) {
  ...
}
```

(Or with variables since I'm actually using Sass: `(min-width: $vertical-view-max + 1) and (max-width: $medium-view-max)`)

Now, I am in the case where I would like the media query to trigger when the width is *not* in this interval.

I found that the following rule works fine:

```
@media (max-width: 768px), (min-width: 1281px) {
  ...
}
```

But I can't make it work with `not` operator:

```
@media (not ((min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1280px))) {
  ...
}
```

I tried different parenthesizations (this one even seems to be invalid syntax). How should I write the rule? Is this not possible at all with the `not` operator?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/ - looks like you use `not all and`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a valid level 4 media query, but [no browser has been updated to support the new grammar yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455958/why-does-not-some-width-xem-media-query-never-fire/24456052#24456052) despite some of them beginning to support some of the new media features. In the meantime, to conform to level 3 with the `not` keyword your media query needs to look like this (with a media type added and all but the innermost pairs of parentheses removed):

```
@media not all and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1280px) {
  ...
}
```

Despite what the apparent shortage of parentheses might suggest, the `not` actually serves to negate the entire media query starting from `all and`.