# Which background-image takes precedence.media query or css?

Tags: css, media-queries, css-specificity

My question is about background-images.  I was designing a home page for iPhone screen and I wanted to use a slightly different image for the mobile version.  My media query was not in a separate css file, just embedded in the index.html.  Problem...the main css image was overriding my query image. I checked for extra brackets etc. I thought the media queries had precedence over the main css? Would I have got my desired result if I had put the Media query in a css link file?

Here is my main css code:

```
#container
{
  background-image:url(images/1000_framec.jpg);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  width:999px;
  height:980px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

and below is my media-query code:

```
@media only screen and max-width 320px {
  #container
  {
    width:98%;
    background:url(images/1000_frameo.jpg) no repeat left;
    margin-top:80px;
    -webkit-background-size:contain;
    -moz-background-size:contain;
    -o-background-size:contain;
    background-size:contain;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Media queries and `@media` rules *are* CSS. But these are [transparent to the cascade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241531/what-are-the-rules-for-css-media-query-overlap/13611538#13611538), so whether you put a style rule in a `@media` rule or not, or whether you place it in a linked stylesheet that has `media="..."` or not, doesn't affect the precedence of that rule in the cascade.

The rest of the [cascading rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html) apply as usual: the most specific selector wins, the last of a series of equally specific selectors wins, an inline style has more precedence over an internal stylesheet, which in turn has more precedence over an external stylesheet, and so on.