# calc() not working within media queries

Tags: css, media-queries, css-calc

```css
@media screen and (max-width: calc(2000px-1px)) { 
  .col { width: 200px; }
}
```

The value after subtraction should be `1999px`, however it does not seem to be working. If I manually change it to `1999px` it works fine, so I know it's not a problem with my CSS. Is `calc` not supported within media queries, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: There's no mention of calc anywhere [in here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries), so I'd guess it's not allowed.

Comment: `calc` doesn't seem to work in media queries from my testing. Sucks.. =[

Answer (score 54):

**ANSWER EDITED AGAIN 21.03.2022:**

In the current version of the spec, using calc (or var) in media queries is NOT supported by [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/#mq-features) (as TylerH pointed out below).

> Properties sometimes accept complex values, e.g., calculations that involve several other values. **Media features*** only accept single values: one keyword, one number, etc.

* Media features include `(max-width: ...)` (or `(... < width < ...)`).

Old specs back to 2012 also explicitly mention **no calc**.

The OP question would definitely have been broken because calc needs whitespace between operators `calc(2000px - 1px)`, but even with whitespace you shouldn't expect or trust it to work reliably.

Browsers that support calc are not actually following the spec.

---

**ANSWER WAS EDITED 13.02.2018:**

Using `calc` in media queries is supported by the spec, but support was only implemented by browsers recently (February 2018). Currently, `calc` in media queries is supported by [Safari Technology Preview 49+](https://webkit.org/blog/8088/release-notes-for-safari-technology-preview-49/), [Chrome 66+](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5643732019838976), and [Firefox 59+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/59). See [MDN's `calc()` page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) for the most up-to-date information.

Comment: According to this issue on Chrome, calc should work in media queries, but it's not implemented: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=421909

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh This bug was requested as a part of MQ L3 or L4(Media Queries Level 4) draft. It's a draft, it can be deleted tomorrow. Not sure that calc will be implemented soon.
Now all modern browsers supports only MQ L1 implementation.

Comment: Calc is allowed in media queries, but functions (including calc) are not supported where media features are used per the spec. https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/#mq-features

Comment: The MDN page has _nothing_ to say about media queries. I'm not sure why this answer is so upvoted.

Comment: I just checked, and `@media screen and (max-width: calc(2000px - 1px)){...}` worked just fine for me. The key is the space between the `-`, so that it knows the difference between `-1px` and `- 1px` (a negative value vs the value to subtract)

Answer (score 14):

Support for use of `calc()` in media queries is browser-dependent HOWEVER the use of mixed units (e.g. em and px at same time) have limited or no current support. Please take a look at [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CSSBurner/vst1L0ad/) (which tests 4 current browsers - Chrome 80.0.3987.163, Opera 67.0.3575.115, Firefox 74.0.1, and Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0) to verify.

For example, these media queries are valid for certain browsers (Chrome 80.0.3987.163, Opera 67.0.3575.115, and Firefox 74.0.1 but NOT Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0)

```
@media (min-width:calc(2em - 1em)) { div { color: green } } // valid

@media (min-width:calc(2px - 1px)) { div { color: green } } // valid
```

whereas this media query is only valid in Firefox 74.0.1

```
@media (min-width:calc(1em - 1px)) { div { color: green } } // different units are "mixed" in same calc() -----> invalid except Firefox
```

UPDATE December 2020: Other functions within the `calc()` family of functions (that is, functions which perform an operation on one or more [calc-sums](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-4/#typedef-calc-sum)) can also be used within a media query. This [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CSSBurner/ky56wh8u/) demonstrates the utility of the [comparison functions `max()`, `min()`, and `clamp()`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-4/#comp-func). These functions are currently supported within a media query by the browsers:

1. Chrome 87
2. Edge 87
3. Firefox 82
4. Opera 72

However, using mixed units within each comparison function is only supported by the following browsers (from the list above):

1. Firefox 82

Comment: Most people don't spend a lot of time researching/displaying full stats. This is an excellent post.

Comment: The Chromium bug which appears to be tracking this is here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=843584

Comment: Note that while functions are supported in some browsers, the spec disallows it. I'd encourage people to avoid using these functions in media queries, as there's no agreed way for them to handle edge cases. (i.e. wait until the spec adds support)

Answer (score 8):

Pinal's answer is great, but your CSS wouldn't work anyways. You need spaces separating your units. In CSS `2000px-1px` would be considered a single value, which obviously isn't a valid unit. It should be `2000px - 1px`.

I'm currently using Chrome 66 and calc works fine in media queries.

Answer (score 2):

There are two specifications relevant to this feature :

- https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/#mq-syntax
- https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-4/#math

The media queries specifications states that some conditions (e.g. `width`) can have a number value.

From the values specification :

> A math function represents a numeric value and can be used wherever such a value would be valid.

These two combined definitely make it required that browsers implement `calc()` and others in media feature values.

This is also tracked by MDN : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media#browser_compatibility

[image: MDN support data for calc in media queries]

Today all browsers support `calc`.

*Some sub features however can have poor support.
For example `aspect-ratio` has mixed support for `calc()` because it's underlying type doesn't support float values. Weirdness like this can make it seem that `calc()` is flaky even when something else is causing issues.*

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for media queries with calc() in IE11 (Up to October 2020).

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Media query</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: powderblue;
        }

        @media screen and (min-width: calc(700px + 1px)) {
            body {
                background-color: yellow;
            }
        }
    </style>
    
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide a source pls?

Comment: Thanks, I added the source in the original answer.