# CSS grid minmax() with max-width of 100%

Tags: html, css, css-grid

This code uses CSS grid with `minmax(30rem, 1fr)`.

```css
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(30rem, 1fr));
```

Everything works fine, but when the <strike>viewport</strike> *parent container* gets smaller than 30rem, a horizontal scrollbar appears. I would need something like `minmax(min(30rem, 100%), 1fr))`. Any idea how to achieve that?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LmEyer

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(30rem, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

li {
  background-color: #aaa;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>grid item</li>
  <li>grid item</li>
  <li>grid item</li>
  <li>grid item</li>
  <li>grid item</li>
  <li>grid item</li>
  <li>grid item</li>
  <li>grid item</li>
  <li>grid item</li>
  <li>grid item</li>
  <li>grid item</li>
  <li>grid item</li>
  <li>grid item</li>
  <li>grid item</li>
  <li>grid item</li>
  <li>grid item</li>
  <li>grid item</li>
  <li>grid item</li>
  <li>grid item</li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You answered the question yourself!!
you can use the `min()` function to achieve this:

> [codepen](https://codepen.io/dannievinther/pen/zYGypyP/0c59fcd56cf2665bbb6baa9a7b5422d2)

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:
    repeat(
      auto-fit,
      minmax(min(100%, 30rem), 1fr)
    );
  gap: 20px;
}
```

I recommend this [article](https://blog.logrocket.com/flexible-layouts-without-media-queries/) to learn more about combine `clamp` and `min()` with `grid-template-column`

Comment: You are right. I guess the function nesting was not available 5 years ago. Or I did a when trying it out.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have a **breakpoint** when the screen width is `30rem`. That calls for a media query.

Add this to your code:

```css
@media (max-width: 30rem) {
   ul { grid-template-columns: 1fr; }
}
```

[**revised codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GdgXKW?editors=1100)

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(30rem, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

li {
  background-color: #aaa;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

@media (max-width: 30rem) {
  ul {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>grid item</li>
  <li>grid item</li>
  <li>grid item</li>
  <li>grid item</li>
  <li>grid item</li>
  <li>grid item</li>
  <li>grid item</li>
  <li>grid item</li>
  <li>grid item</li>
  <li>grid item</li>
  <li>grid item</li>
  <li>grid item</li>
  <li>grid item</li>
  <li>grid item</li>
  <li>grid item</li>
  <li>grid item</li>
  <li>grid item</li>
  <li>grid item</li>
  <li>grid item</li>
<ul>
```

Comment: 1. The media query should take the grid-gap into account. So it should read `@media (max-width: calc(30rem + 2 * 10px))`, but that is [not widely supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667208/calc-not-working-within-media-queries), currently.

Comment: 2. Unfortunately, this only works if the grid is on root level. It does not work if this grid is in a container narrower than the viewport. (Yes, my original question was about viewport. But that was for simplicity.)

Comment: No need to factor in a grid-column-gap (which only render *between* items). Once the screen reaches 30rem, there is only one column, and no gap. @mhchem

Comment: 1. @Michael_B Yes and no. It's not the grid-gap, you are right about that. But 30rem is not the correct value to avoid scrollbars (tested your codepen in several browsers). In this case, it's the `body`'s margin that you have to factor in.