# calc() with viewport units in media query on supported browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, sass, media-queries

Using `calc()` in a media query in Chrome (version 68) seems to replace viewport units with `px`. Eg

```
@media only screen and (min-height: calc(100vw + 10px))
```

results in

```
@media only screen and (min-height: 110px)
```

Firefox handles it correctly and IE, Edge and Safari which doesn't support `calc()` in media queries (according to [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)) seems to ignore the query which is better for my use case.

How can I apply the media query + calc() in the browsers that properly supports it? Should I expect Firefox to continue supporting `calc()` this way?

Use case: In a game on a square canvas that fills the viewport, a signature should appear in the lower right corner of either the canvas (default) or the viewport depending on the available space.

Demo: https://codepen.io/LoveF/pen/PBjXwr

Comment: Are you sure it's Chrome doing that and not sass?

Comment: Appear to be a bug in Chrome: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=421909 ... and this question cover that so might be a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667208/calc-not-working-within-media-queries

Comment: @HereticMonkey, considering that it works in Firefox, I would say it is Chrome that is faulty. Also codepen can display the compiled css and it looks fine to me: `calc(100vh - 50px + 2 * (2 * 18px + 100px))`

Comment: @LGSon, I too think it is a bug. The unfortunate result is that Chrome does a miscalculation rather then to fallback to the default such as IE, Edge and Safari does, which would have been better. Maybe they will fix it but what to do until then? I also saw [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667208/calc-not-working-within-media-queries), I think it is related but not a duplicate as `calc(2000px - 1px)` gives the correct result.

Comment: @Love I would go for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia