# Media query with vh and calc in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, media-queries, css-calc

Is there a way to use `calc` with `vh` unit in media query for width?

I'm running following code in Chrome 71 (support of `calc` in media-queries [was added in 66](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5643732019838976)), but see following result: `calc` with `px` works (red), `vh` without `calc` works (blue), but they together don't (green).

In firefox everything is fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/tmor5yvh/

```css
@media all and (min-width: calc(20px - 17px)) {
  body {
    background: red;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 100vh) {
  body {
    background: blue;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: calc(100vh - 17px)) {
  body {
    background: green;
  }
}
```

PS: Condition means "width without 17px (for vertical scrollbar) is less then height".

Comment: This might be of use to you: [Chrome Bug Report: calc in Media Queries evaluates to a fixed value](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=915190). From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51522724/calc-with-viewport-units-in-media-query-on-supported-browsers), it seems like there's a bug in Chrome, where `vw` and `vh` height values are translated into fixed values. For example, `calc(100vh - 17px)` is misread by Chrome to be `calc(100px - 17px)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, changing your media query to `calc(500vh - 17px)` proves this. It changes to green when the width becomes `517px`.

Comment: @TylerRoper, any workaround?

Comment: Certainly not one I know off the top of my head unfortunately, I haven't dealt with this issue - just felt it was interesting so I did some digging. I'd suggest digging into the chrome bug I linked and see if any of the comments suggest a workaround.

Comment: Use JavaScript. CSS doesn't even know the width of the scrollbar, which may or may not be 17px.

Comment: Use `em` instead of px and see if that works. something like this `(max-width: calc(100vh - 2.5em) `

Comment: @Nisarg, doesn't seem working...