# Do media queries inherit values that are not specified within a media query?

Tags: css, inheritance, media-queries

I am using media queries and flex box to make my site responsive, I think I am being a bit dumb here but say i have the css class of wrapper, as follows:

```
 .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    height: 80px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #eee;
 }
```

What values does the media query of (max-width: 450px) inherit? or does it not inherit any?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  .wrapper {
    height: 50px;
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: All values . Media querie doesn't mean replace at all the definition for the class is just cascade. Use the inspector

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043001/what-is-the-meaning-of-cascading-in-css

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Media Queries 'inherit' *all* the properties of the original element, and apply the specified changes in the actual media query.

Thus, your snippet effectively translates to:

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    height: 80px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #eee;
 }

@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    height: 80px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #eee;

    /* And then your changes, which override earlier properties */
    height: 50px;
  }
}
```

This makes it possible to simply design an UI once, and modify *that* UI for various devices without having to copy paste the entire code into various Media Queries all the time, which would increase maintenance, size of the CSS and becoming more error-prone (i.e. you'll be forced to make edits in multiple places, you could forget and edit somewhere when making changes, and all sorts of nasty stuff).

To elaborate a little; overlapping media queries can also influence each other when they effect a certain element and compete. In which case the *latter specified* one would be the displayed one when the media query is put into effect. Disregarding `!important` tags, obviously. An more elaborate answer on this matter is discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241531/what-are-the-rules-for-css-media-query-overlap) SO question.

The rules for these kind of situations are specified in the CSS *Cascading* and *Inheritance* rules, which are quite elaborately explained at [Mozilla's Developer website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Great answer!
I get it now!

Answer (score 1):

CSS rules in media queries "inherit" all parameter values that are not overwritten by it from other rules that apply to the same selector which are *above* it in the stylesheet. So in your case everything with the exception of `height`

(Actually, they don't *inherit* that, but the regular parameter values simply continue to apply for all sizes and are not overwritten by a media query that doesn't contain that particular parameter)

Comment: To be accurate the height too but is overwritten

Comment: @DaniP well, that's maybe a bit philsophical, but I aready added something that also goes in that direction