# Optimizing css for a media query

Tags: css, media-queries

Good morning,

I have created a media query for my website. I have the feeling that it is slowing down my website, because it is not optimized.
On mobile phones, I have a specific image. For tablets and desktops I have another image to be shown.
The media query I have works just fine. But it is not optimized.
Can anyone help me to get it optimized?

this is the query:

```
body, html {
    height : 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px)  {

.Frontpage-image {
    background-image: url("https://dit.be/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/mobiel-01.svg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) {
    .Frontpage-image {
        background-image:url("https://dit.be/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/desktop-01.svg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        background-size: cover;
        height:100vh;
    }
}
    

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .Frontpage-image{
        background-image:url("https://dit.be/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/desktop-01.svg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 100vh;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
    .Frontpage-image {
        background-image:url("https://dit.be/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/desktop-01.svg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        background-size: cover;
        height:100vh;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, do you mean shorter/neater code or runtime optimisation?

Comment: Both actually, but runtime optimisation is more important for me

Comment: There is a code review stackexchange site for this at the bottom of this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this CSS code.

In media query, styles defined outside of query is inherited.
So my code works exactly like yours, but the code has been greatly reduced.

```
body, html {
    height : 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
}
.Frontpage-image {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px)  {

.Frontpage-image {
    background-image: url("https://dit.be/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/mobiel-01.svg");
}
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) {
    .Frontpage-image {
        background-image:url("https://dit.be/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/desktop-01.svg");
    }
}
    

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .Frontpage-image{
        background-image:url("https://dit.be/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/desktop-01.svg");
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
    .Frontpage-image {
        background-image:url("https://dit.be/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/desktop-01.svg");
    }
}
```

You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42811839/do-media-queries-inherit-values-that-are-not-specified-within-a-media-query).

Comment: Please could you give an explanation describing how the code works to optimise things, thanks.

Comment: Plase check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, the code is reduced but it always loads the first image, whether it's needed or not so there's a run time overhead (which is what I think the question is about).

Answer (score -1):

Here are some tips to optimize this

1. Use Low size images
2. Use Low size videos or embed them from YouTube or Vimeo
3. Compress this CSS code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).