# Select one of two layouts depending on screen width

Tags: css, media-queries

I have two different layouts in CSS. One is for mobile (and other narrower screens) and the second one is for desktop. Width of the layout depends on screen width.

```css
/* mobile */
@media (max-width: 25rem) {
    .foo {
        font-size: 1rem;
        color: red;
    }
}

/* desktop */
@media (min-width: 25rem) {
.foo {
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
}
```

I don't want to reset things that are set in the “mobile” part in the “desktop” part because they are quite different.

When the screen width is exactly 25rem both layouts are applied. How can I prevent this situation?

Comment: You can try `@media (min-width: 25.1rem)` Or technically speaking, you dont need a media query for mobile. Just for the desktop.

Comment: @JonesJoseph I know one media query is enough but there is quite a lot of code and code that would reset properties set for mobile could be quite long.

Comment: @JonesJoseph And what if user has screen width between 25rem and 25.1rem (not inclusive).

Comment: Well you are right but i wonder if such a rare case scenario will occur

Comment: [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13611538/4759033)

Comment: So I have to set all values from “mobile” back in the “desktop” media? There is really no other option?