# Combining small phone media queries with bootstrap media queries

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm using the standard bootstrap 3 media queries that use max-width, but also want to include some for smaller phones and tablets, but can't figure out how to get them both to work for their respective devices.

For example I know this will handle any most phones:

```
@media (max-width:767px)
```

But if I want to have a separate queries for say, iphone 5's like this

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 568px)
```

Either one or the other will work.

I've tried changing the order (as I know the later one will override the earlier one) and adding "!important" declarations, but nothing seems to work.

Int this particular instance I have series of links with a button below them and need to have the padding between them be smaller so they will all fit on a smaller screens (in this example an iPhone 5, but I'd like to have a 3rd one for iPhone 4 etc.), but not be to close together on the bigger one.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks in advance for any help you can be.

Here's a rough example of what I tried for 3 different sizes.

/*iPhone 4 and other small phones*/

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px){
    .topic-link h5 {
        padding-bottom:12px;
    }
}
```

/*iPhone 5 and other medium phones*/

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 568px){
    .topic-link h5 {
        padding-bottom:18px;
    }
}
```

/*iPhone 6 and other large phones*/

```
@media (max-width:767px){
    .topic-link h5 {
        padding-bottom:24px;
    }
}
```

Here's attempt number 2:

/*iPhone 4 and other small phones*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px)and (max-width: 480px) {

/*iPhone 5 and other medium phones*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 568px) {

/*iPhone 6 and other large phones*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 375px) and (max-width: 667px) {

Comment: Please read our Help section on how to create an  MCVE
(http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add it to your question.
You will get faster, better help from the community that way.

Comment: I just added an example to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest either being more specific with your rules (for example your `min-device-width` for iPhone 5 could be larger than the previous max and so on.), or using `min-width` in the manner suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10322199/2594119) answer.  Perhaps give [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18500871/2594119) a read as well in regards to using `min-width` vs `min-device-width`.

Comment: Thanks so much @gffbss. I think I've almost got it...:-) 

I understand now that I want to use a combination of min and max width vs. min-device-width and max-device-width, and that it's the combination of min and max width, in the right order, that will get this to work, but I can't seem to get both of the smaller queries to work because they both have the same min width (320px).

I tried having the iphone 4 query be just max width, but that didn't work either.

I've updated my original post with my 2nd attempt.