# media query min-width not working

Tags: mpmediaquery

I am using media query, no matter the browser is below or over 1200px, the the css always detects my browser min-width is 768px.so the display in browser is always 750px.

maybe it's a easy problem but it bothered me few hours.

My HTML:

```
<div class="header_1">
            <div class="logo_1">
                <a href="Learn.html">
                    <img src="img/logo.svg">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="sign_in">
                <ul class="sign_list_1">
                    <li>Pricing</li>
                    <li>Sign in</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
</div>

My CSS:
@media (min-width: 1200px){
    .header_1{
        width: 1170px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px){
.header_1{
    width:970px;}
}

@media (min-width: 768px){
.header_1{
        width: 750px;
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306670/css-specificity-media-queries-and-min-width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reversing the order of your media queries. The last rule (768px) overrides the others because it is last and has equal precedence to the others.

Answer (score 6):

In HTML `<head>` add

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Use `max-width` instead of `min-width`

```
@media all and (max-width: 1200px) {
   /* Your CSS Rules */
}

@media all and (max-width: 992px) {
   /* Your CSS rules */
}

@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
   /* Your CSS rules */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are matching whatever query has come last. This become easier if you are  explicit with your media queries - use the **and** operator so the order is not important.

For example for the small band:
`(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px)`

So this media only applies for widths between 768px and 991px.

You would apply this right up to a pixel below the next band. For the top band you don't need a max width.

Answer (score -1):

In my case it stopped working because some css definition above was missing closing "}".